# How do I change the color of div on a page from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Since I'm still learning the `localStorage` and `cookie` techniques, I am trying to change the color of the div on `page1.html` from `page2.html` by using the submit button, color of the div should be changed permanently when the user clicks submit button on `page2.html`
This is what I got on page1:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("circleBase type1");
    for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        anchors[i].onclick = function() {
            window.open("EnterInformation.html");
        }
    }
}
```

on page2 i used `localStorage` for saving data permanently, with this save I need to change the color of the div on page1. 
This is page2 so far:

```
 function SaveInfo() {
        localStorage.Yritys = $('#Yritys').val();
        localStorage.Henkilönimi = $('#Henkilönimi').val();
        localStorage.Asema_yrityksessa = $('#Asema_yrityksessa').val();
        localStorage.Puhelin_Nr = $("#Puhelin_Nr").val();
        localStorage.e_Mail = $('#e_Mail').val();
        localStorage.Keskustelun_aihe = $('#Keskustelun_aihe').val();
```

What would be the solution to this? It would be nice to use `localStorage` instead of cookies. Thank You!

Comment: Why is there a java tag? JavaScript != Java

Comment: lol, my bad, it should stand JavaScript, pressed space to early

Comment: I hope I get your question and description of how your pages interact right: 1. give your div a unique id. 2. If you load page1, after having saved the color to localStorage before leaving page2, read the color-value from your localStorage. 3. Use JQuery to find your div by id and set the color.

Comment: this is the short verions in page1 is a div that looks like a circle and when it is pressed it opens page 2 in which user enters information, when he hits submit the page2 should close and return to page1 and change the div(circle) color to red! should I anyhow save the color of div to LS for further use or is there another way?
@DiabolicWords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a local storage

```
myCustomColor = '#2B2A28';
localStorage.setItem('myDataStorage', myCustomColor);
```

Then retrieve them

```
var myLoadedColor = localStorage.getItem('myDataStorage');
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.backgroundColor = myLoadedColor;
```

myDataStorage is the name of your created localStorage. You can use different names to create multiple localStorages if you would.

You can .getItem on the localStorage upon page load and then set the color of your div based on that localStorage data.

Comment: okay, this works, but what if I had more of the same divs the problem is i have them somewhere between 60-100 and they have the same class, how would the app know which 1 to fill, is there a way from the code, and not just by adding id's to the whole lot? if the user presses 1 particular div, only that div out of 100 identical should change.

Comment: I haven't mentioned this in the question, since in the last couple of days, there haven't been many answers. So I'm sorry if I'm troubling You :/

Comment: The ID property is there for a reason. No I don't think there is any other way than specifying an id for each div. Adding and utilising unique names is one of the fundamentals of coding.

Comment: If it works I'll totally appreciate an upvote at least, if you won't accept it as an answer hahaha. Anyway, since you have 60-100 divs I don't think there is any other easier way than assigning ids one by one, assigning localstorages one by one.

Comment: i thought that it could be done by className, but then I'll get to work, I will accept it as an answer, since You answered the question I asked in the first place :D

Comment: Oh and can I use this method in page 2 even if page 1 contains the div?

Comment: Since you are going to use HTML5 Local Storage, this should work across all pages.

Comment: Of course you can search for the/a <div> with the matching class supposed this class is unique. This is what it is all about. 'name' and 'id' and even 'class' are properties you can use to mark your elements in a way that they are recognizable and singular among all the others of the same type. Well, 'class' should rather be used for behaviour- and styling purposes but it's not forbidden to use it.  TO BE CONTINUED with a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

This little piece of code scans your page for all elements with the matching class and changes the background color then. Of course you can use it also for single elements:

```
var x = document.getElementByClassName("example");
x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

But in this case JavaScript will only change the first div it finds with a matching class.

To sum it up: There is no other convenient way than marking/tagging your elements in a way that they are unique and recognizable. Normally this is done by the name or the id. Class would also work but is seldomly used in this way.

Well, actually you could also iterate through the DOM and count the elments in order to change let's say the 15th div that appears. But what if you add additional divs a couple of days later? It's a very uncomfortable approach.

Use the localStorage and it will work using names or ids. You only have once to give every div it's id and/or name.